# is this responsive css composition possible only with css?

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, flexbox

i have this layout.
[image: image - what i need]

I have bootstrap 3 included if needed. I'm having trouble to make this blue background div (containing text) stretch full width beneath image.

Closest I got is making 2 (bs grid) columns, and then using flexbox first on container of columns to make them stretch to same height, and then flex on left column to make content verticaly centered. But then this blue background is only on left side, not stretching full width.

[image: image - what i have]

Can this be made by using css only? if I make one column and have blue bg div stretch full width, i must absolutely position image on right side - but then I don't have image's height.

edit: here's fiddle of what i currently have:

> ## this is previous section
>
> ```
> <div class="row flexrow">
>
>   <!-- left column -->
>   <div class="col-sm-6 flexcolumn">
>
>     <div class="row bluebg">
>
>       <h2>HEADING</h2>
>       <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
>
>     </div>
>
>   </div>
>
>   <!-- right column -->
>   <div class="col-sm-6">
>     <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/q9ak7h9ah/image.png" class="wow fadeIn img-responsive" data-wow-duration="0.7s"
> ```
>
> data-wow-delay="0.3s">
>
> ```
> </div>
> <!-- row -->
> ```
>
> ## this is next section

[my fiddle - current layout](https://jsfiddle.net/5461qabu/)

Comment: What have you tried? I assume that you've used bootstrap grid system, which uses floats. For this kind of layout you'd need `position:absolute` on either `img` or `heading`

Comment: if i position:absolute on img, i loose image height for making it responsive (proportional on right column width)

Comment: We can't debug an image, so for a proper answer, post a working code snippet that reproduce the issue you describe, or else you will just get guesses like the given answer.

Comment: @Yuray Can `img` height be less than `heading` height, or is it _always_ bigger?

Comment: it is always bigger (height is bigger than blue background div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Image should be `position:absolute` if you want it to overlap on another.
Change your `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-12` under comment `<!-- left column -->`

I have modified your code below

```css
section#prev,
section#next {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bluebg {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 200, .5);
}

section#mainsection {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexrow {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;/*add this*/
  top: 0;/*add this*/
  left: 0;/*add this*/
  height: 299px;/*add this*/
}

.flexcolumn {
  display: block; /*update this*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%; /*add this*/
  margin-top: 90px; /*add this*/
}
/*add below code*/
.newclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50px;
}

.bluebg p {
    width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<section id="prev">
  <h1>
  this is previous section
  </h1>
</section>


<section id="mainsection">


  <div class="container-fluid">


    <div class="row flexrow">

      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="col-sm-12 flexcolumn">

       <div class="row bluebg">

          <h2>HEADING</h2>
          <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>

       </div>
        <!-- right column -->
      <div class="newclass">
        <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/q9ak7h9ah/image.png" class="wow fadeIn img-responsive" data-wow-duration="0.7s" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
      </div>

      </div>

     

    </div>
    <!-- row -->

  </div>
  <!-- container -->

</section>


<section id="next">
  <h1>
  this is next section
  </h1>
</section>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it promises :), but if you go full page, you see that blue bg is not stretched full width...

Comment: answer updated. please check I have made some changes into .flexcolumn

Comment: thank you, although it's not quite what i wanted (since i have to hard code margins and img height) i will use your solution and add more break points to achieve what i need.

Comment: You can use values in % instead of pixels to avoid too much of break points.